# SQL Server select statment

Tags: sql-server, select, replace, replaceall

I have over 2000 rows, and I want to replace the text in these formats:

```
lorem ipsum (123456) lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
```

What I need is to remove the `(123456)` from all products for all 2000+ rows.

Comment: Removed the `plsql` tag - that would be for **Oracle** PL/SQL - not SQL Server

Comment: You mean ? : update mytable set myfield = replace(myfield, '(123456)', '')

Comment: item a (1234) for men 
item b (986) for kids

I need these items like this 

item a for men
item b for men

Comment: If you have differing strings (some with multiple replacements required) you should be detailing that in your question, @MohammedBazbazat . That isn't explained in your question at all. Seems like what you are after is Regex replacement. SQL Server doesn't natively support regex, so you'll be better off looking at clr functions in my opinion.

Comment: You ask a question, you get an answerh, then you come with "oh, i have diferent strings, my problem is acutally different". Sorry, we can not help you if you do not sit down and organize your thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `STUFF` function to achieve this:

```
DECLARE @S VARCHAR(MAX)='lorem ipsum (123456) lorem ipsum lorem ipsum'

SELECT STUFF(@S,PATINDEX('%[()0-9]%', @S),CHARINDEX(')', @S, PATINDEX('% [()0-9]%', @S))-PATINDEX('%[()0-9]%', @S)+1,'')
```